# Issues with loading custom Omniauth provider in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise, omniauth

I'm having issues with setting up a custom OmniAuth strategy to use with Devise. Im using the following gem here but im unsure on how to properly load this file and use it.

https://github.com/aereal/omniauth-xauth

Based on the README, i created a subclass specific for my provider, i didn't know really where to place this file, so i placed it here  `lib/strategies/myauth.rb` based on this **[article](http://www.polyglotprogramminginc.com/writing-a-non-gemified-strategy-for-omniauth/)**. The file looks something like this. Removing the provider specific code.

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Myauth < OmniAuth::Strategies::XAuth
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Based on this [article](http://www.polyglotprogramminginc.com/writing-a-non-gemified-strategy-for-omniauth/) i added the following code to my `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    module XAuth
      autoload :myauth, Rails.root.join('lib', 'strategies', 'myauth') 
    end
  end
end
```

I did **not** add the following code, since i've read that by adding the `config.omniauth :myauth` in my `config/initializers/devise.rb` will take care of loading it. ??

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :myauth
end
```

---

I also added the following to my `user.rb`

`devise :database_authenticatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:myauth]`

I've also updated my `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :myauth, 'CKEY', 'CSEC', strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::XAuth::Myauth
```

So when i try and run `rails s` i get the following error output.

```
`load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Myauth, expected ...../PROJECT/lib/strategies/myauth.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Any ideas on what im missing? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need config/initializers/omniauth.rb file as you already have myauth.rb.

Your strategy class should contain the following:

```
config.omniauth :myauth, 'CKEY', 'CSEC', strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Myauth
```

Rest should work as long as the content of Myauth class is right.

Please let me know if i have misunderstood your question and answered incorrectly.